# How to prevent UIWebView from fitting page content to screen width (neither scaled nor reflowed)?

Tags: ios, webview, uiwebview, responsive

I use `UIWebView` to load a web page in my app and I want the page be rendered to the exact same layout as it is on PC browser, without any "responsive" effect.

The specific page in problem is generated by coping a table from MS Word to `ckeditor`.  The page's complete source code is listed as below (sorry for some Chinese characters in the page; they should have nothing to do with the nature of the problem):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.10/full/contents.css">
    <title>My Page</title>
  </head>
  <body class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p align="center">时间</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">体温</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">症状</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">WBC</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">N%</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">TB</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">DB</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">ALB</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">ALT</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">AST</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">PT</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">h-CRP</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">PCT</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p align="center">10/20</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">39.9</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">4.28</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">91.3</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">1.25</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p align="center">10/21</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">39.3</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">3.37</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">85.5</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">57.6</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">19.4</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">29.6</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">18</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">23</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">20.1</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">2.11</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p align="center">10/22</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">乏力纳差，轻度腹胀</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p align="center">10/25</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">37.4</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">1.58</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">72.2</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">27.7</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">16.0</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">29.4</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">1.2</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">14</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">0.39</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p align="center">10/25</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">4.85</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">89.1</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center">93.26</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p align="center"><br></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

In PC browser, and in Android's webview, the result layout of the page is like:

[image]

But in iOS's `UIWebView`, it is like:
[image]

How should I do with `UIWebView` to make the page be rendered the same as it is in PC browser?

---

**UPDATE**:

Adding a viewport meta with a large enough hard-coded width value in the page's source code will get what I want:

`<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=1000, initial-scale = 1.0, minimum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = yes">`

But this doesn't seem to be the right way to achieve this.  I always thought if I want the page to be reflowed then I need to add a viewport meta with `width=device-width`, but if I want the page to be neither **scaled** nor **reflowed** then I don't need to setup anything.  Not the case for iOS UIWebView?

Comment: set common width for td which have the text

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Vinodh.  However, the html source is not under my control.  Decorating the html page itself may not be a viable solution in this case.  I always thought I need to do extra stuff in order to make page content to fit screen width while the default case will always let the page content flow as if the screen width is infinitive (which is the case for me on Android's webview).  Seems not the case for iOS's webview?

Comment: okay , then add scalepagetofit property in Uiwebview

Comment: Adding scalepagetofit property will make the page zoom to fit the screen width.  I don't want the page to be **scaled** or **reflowed**.  I just want the page to be rendered the same way as in a PC browser (and also Android's webview with its default settings).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this before you are creating  webview

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

or try like this

```
 String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
 mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
```

Comment: Sadly adding this doesn't change the way the page is displayed on the phone.

Comment: Note that userAgent needs to be changed before creation of UIWebView, not before loading URL.

Comment: Sure i will change that

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sample" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil]];
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

[image]
After zooming

[image]

Comment: This will make the page to be **scaled**.  I need the page to be neither **scaled** nor **reflowed**.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the left and right margin. It will prevent UIWebView from fitting page content to screen width.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  Just tried and sadly it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding CSS:

```
td { white-space: nowrap; }
```